# Add EventLog output to an existing .NET application already using ILoggerFactory

Tags: .net, logging, dependency-injection, event-log

I have a .NET 7 web application that uses an injected `ILoggerFactory` to log.

In our development environments we get that output in the console, which is fine.

On a Windows Server with IIS I want to redirect this logging output to the system event log.

I can do this *in* the app with DI:

```cs
// Program.cs
var builder = WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args);
...
// Add Windows EventLog
builder.ConfigureLogging(l => l.AddEventLog(...));
```

However, this then means my app will *only* run on Windows (`AddEventLog` will crash on any non-Windows server) and I don't want that.

In addition `AddEventLog` can hard code application name, but that crashes if not already registered in the event log (default is `"Application"` and `".NET Runtime"`, which isn't much use) so I'd want the event log to be set up in configuration, not hard coded.

It looks like this is [*already* in `CreateDefaultBuilder`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/d4a59b36c679712b74eccf98deb1a362cdbaa6b1/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting/src/HostingHostBuilderExtensions.cs#L272-L301):

```cs
// HostingHostBuilderExtensions.cs > AddDefaultServices
bool isWindows = RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows);
...
if (isWindows)
    // Add the EventLogLoggerProvider on windows machines
    logging.AddEventLog();
```

Which would suggest that all I need to do is add a config section to `appSettings.json`:

```json
{
  "Logging": {
    "EventLog": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Information"
      },
      "SourceName": "My App"
    }
  }
  ...
```

But adding this config section does nothing - only the console logging seems to be set up by `CreateDefaultBuilder`.

It seems I can use the `DOTNET_STARTUP_HOOKS` environmental variable (which is very poorly documented, but is what Azure and the like use) to add something like:

```
internal class StartupHook
{
    public static void Initialize() {
        // override app to output to Event Log
        // loading dependencies here is nasty
        // we don't have access to the app builder and AddEventLog()
        // so probably have to kludge Console.SetOut somehow
    }
}
```

Then I can set this variable in Windows and skip it in other hosting environments that don't support event log.

However, this feels like a *lot* of messing about with an advanced undocumented feature to do something that must be really common practice. Surely I'm not the first .NET developer to not want a limiting Windows dependency just to set logging output?

- Is there a way to add the built-in .NET event log output to an existing, complied .NET app with existing config features?
- Why is the code that's apparently in `CreateDefaultBuilder` ignored?
- Alternatively, if I *must* use `DOTNET_STARTUP_HOOKS` I can't be the first to need this, has someone already written it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These problems are due to multiple patterns for running and configuring the web app over the years, and any attempt to Google one of them finds similar looking documentation for the others, which is a pain.

There are 3 iterations of this, and I'm using the oldest:

- `WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder` is the minimal builder that shipped with .NET Core 1, back when the idea was to keep it incredibly minimal and manually add everything. At some point (.NET Core 2 I think) `UseKestrel`/`UseIIS` was baked in, but it doesn't include logging.
- `Host.CreateDefaultBuilder` is a rebuild (.NET 5) that makes this generic to apps other than websites. It adds support for event log that the original `WebHost` variant lacked.
- `WebApplication.CreateBuilder` simplified this in .NET 6, but is incompatible with the `Startup.cs` used by the previous two.

Upgrade and event logging works, but ignores `appsettings.json`, but that appears to be a bug in .NET: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/80724

You can work around this by manually re-registering the event logger provider:

```cs
    [System.Runtime.Versioning.SupportedOSPlatform("windows")]
    public static void SetEventLogConfig(WebApplicationBuilder builder) {
        string? eventLog = builder.Configuration["Logging:EventLog:SourceName"];
        if(eventLog is not null)
            builder.Logging.AddEventLog(c => c.SourceName = eventLog);
    }

// then in program.cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
...
if(RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows))
    SetEventLogConfig(builder);
```